# How to autoplay embed google drive video?

Tags: php, html, embed

I'have uploaded the video in google drive and trying to use the link in my website. The video should be auto-play. i have tried **?autoplay=1** and **?start=1** after the url. But video does not autoplay.

Please anyone suggest me an idea.

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://pacificu.libguides.com/c.php?g=495911&p=3395956) to see instructions on the embedding, maybe you're missing a step!

Comment: @AMolina — What makes you think the OP is using Moodle?! And that page says nothing about autoplaying the video.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for the catch, I misread the instructions as more general, apologies!